# Within a With <obj> / End With block, is there a keyword to access <obj> directly?

Tags: vb.net, with-statement

In VB.NET, just wondering if there is a kind of "this" keyword, with which one can access the object being used with in `With <obj>` ... `End With` block. Eg:

```
With myObj
  .thisMethod()
  someFunction(<this>) ' Where "<this>" refers to myObj
  .thatMethod()
End With
```

It would just be handy if it were possible, in those times you want to pass myObj without leaving the With block.

Comment: Why can't you just use the object name like this:  `someFunction(myObj)`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that directly no. The only way I can think of doing this is to extend your object to include a reference to itself as a readonly property:

```
Public Class TextBoxExtended
    Inherits TextBox
    Public ReadOnly Property ObjRef As TextBox
        Get
            Return Me
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

You can then do this in your with Block:

```
With myObj
  .thisMethod()
  someFunction(.ObjRef)
  .thatMethod()
End With
```

However I would have to question why you would want to do this.

Comment: Thanks, and that's a good workaround. The reason is just convenience really, and curiosity. In the same way "Me" is useful within a class, referring to the With object can be useful inside a long With block.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite follow you. Why can you refer to the object?

For example if that was a textfield.

```
With textbox1
.visible = true
.text = textbox1.text
End with
```

That would still work.

in fact this would also work.

```
.text = .text
```

Maybe not the best as you will never see a change...

Lets try one more relevent...

```
' The function to send to.
Function myfunction(thestring As String) As String
    thestring += "moretext"
    Return thestring
End Function

' The with statement
With Textbox1
.Text = myfunction(.Text)
End With
```

The textbox text will change to the original text + "moretext".

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, but I want to refer to the object *used* on the With line. This may be a long line which equates to an object, which I wouldn't want to repeat within the With block. Your example of `.Text = myfunction(.Text)` is not what I'm after. It should read `.Text = myfunction(Textbox1)`. But I'm curious whether I can refer to the object `Textbox1` using a *keyword*, not the variable name itself - if possible.

Comment: As in is there a keyword for the object you are using? Like textbox1 being referred to in a similar way to a formed being referred to by me.?

I don't think there is, and i can't think of a way it would be useful. You example of .text = myfunction(Textbox1) wouldn't work because texbox1 isn't a function. But if it did have some kind of action it should work. In which case i don't see how textbox1 would be harder to refer to than a keyword for it.